# How to query mongodb collection field names from R mongolite package

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I would like to return the field names of a given mongodb collection from R mongolite.

Starting from mongolite recent versions (i.e 1.5+), you can run a raw command on the mongodb, I can use the below for instance to return all the collections:

```
m = mongo(db = 'dbname', url='urlofdb')
m$run('{"listCollections":1}')
```

This would return a list of collection:

```
$cursor
$cursor$id
[1] 0

$cursor$ns
[1] "db.$cmd.listCollections"

$cursor$firstBatch
                           name       type          readOnly     idIndex.v   idIndex._id idIndex.name            idIndex.ns
1                    collection-name  collection    FALSE         1           1           _id_                   db.collection
```

Can you please advise how I could return the column names of a given collection using the run command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really can do it directly.

If you could, that would largely go against the entire philosophy of a NoSQL-database (which Mongo is). The idea behind a NoSQL-database is that you have a collection of documents, which can all have their own fields.
The analogy to paper documents really does work, and the concept of 'columns' is replaced by 'fields', which don't pertain to the collection as a whole, but to individual documents, and each document can contain anything. And there is no overarching mandatory template into which everything must fit. In practice, a lot of documents will have a similar structure, but this is by no means guaranteed. This means that it's entirely possible that you have 100 million documents with 3 fields called "a", "b" and "c", and that document 100000001 has 4 fields: a, b, c and d.

It could be that the database-engine keeps track of what fields are somewhere in a collection, but I doubt that. And if it doesn't, the only way to get all four names a, b, c and d, is to go through all 100000001 documents (or more), which will take a while. Undoubtedly, some optimisation is implemented, but it will always be a hard question.

If you just want an answer for a small DB, I think simply querying for all documents and taking the column-names of the resulting data.frame is easiest.

But if your database is large, this question is no longer about R or mongolite, and I'm not sufficient enough in working with Mongo to help you further.

Comment: Thanks Emil for the answer, Yes i tend to read large collection just to get the names. Maybe I'll read the last document and get its name as a workaround for now.

Comment: It's not the that the last document will get you all names either! It was just an example where the last document had all the names, but basically any document can have a fieldname that is not in any of the other documents. To get a good impression you could collect a sample and take those names, but you can never be sure you have everything, except for reading it all. Sampling can be accomplished with `names(MyMon$aggregate('[{"$sample": {"size": 100}}]'))` or similar.

Comment: Thanks Emil again, Yes I'm aware of what you meant. I only said so as we append to our data and I was concerned by recent documents.
And yes, I had the sample approach in my mind :)